# How can one incorporate heuristic algorithms in MiniZinc?

Tags: optimization, heuristics, minizinc

Suppose I have an order batching problem (in a warehouse context) that I will like to solve with the aid of heuristics. In particular, I want to implement some well-known heuristics for warehouses with multiple cross aisles, such as the S-shape and Largest gap heuristics.

How can I implement them in MiniZinc? Is it possible to do so?

I looked up its documentation, but I could only find MiniSearch, which is a language for specifying meta-search in a MiniZinc model. (http://www.minizinc.org/minisearch/documentation.html)

Some insight into this will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question heavily depends on the nature of your heuristic. From the MiniZinc aspect I would identify three kinds of heuristics:

1. *Solving heuristics*: heuristic algorithms that solve a model instance, but might not give the optimal solution.
2. *Search heuristics*: heuristic algorithms that provide (good) indications of what is best to search next.
3. *Partial heuristics*: heuristics that can solve part of the model instance, but can't solve the full model instance.

There is no straightforward MiniZinc-way of dealing with heuristics and you might need some creativity to implement your heuristic in a useable way. Here are some pointers to possible solutions:

In case you are dealing with a solving heuristics, you might not need to do any work; it already give you an solution. However, if you want to verify the solution or ensure an optimal solution, then you can consider running the model with the solution or using the solution as a warm start (respectively). (You could even implement the heuristic as a FlatZinc solver if it's broad enough, but consider the time investment vs. it's usability.)

In the other two cases the well known solution is to *pre-compute the heuristics* and include them within the model data. In case of a search heuristic it might be possible to compute the order in which the variables should be searched. You can then use this order in the `input_order` search heuristic. For a partial heuristic it is possible to precompute the partial model and include this directly in the model. This is often too constraining for the problem. Instead if you can compute multiple partial solutions, these can be included as a `table` constraint.

The previous solutions would only be possible if the heuristic algorithm does not depend on the domains of the variables within the search. When they do, we generally talk about "meta-search". This is were implementations like MiniSearch come in. In MiniSearch you can for example reflect on the last solution or last assignment and base new search behaviour on those values. This allows these more dynamic heuristics to be implemented.

Even MiniSearch does not generally run at every node. So in some situations you might not be able to use your heuristic in MiniZinc directly. An option in that case would be to add your heuristic to a FlatZinc solver and then call it using an designated annotation.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed breakdown! :) With regards to the pointers raised, I will say that I am focusing on solving heuristics. For this, do you mean that I have to create a solver myself (like Gecode)?

Comment: also, what do you mean by "using the solution as a warm start (respectively)"? Sorry about that.. I'm rather new to MiniZinc and the use of optimization software in solving optimization problems..

Comment: Some solvers support a search annotation `warm_start` which will allow you to start the search from a solution, this can be a very effective mechanism when you have an indication of a solution. You could for a heuristic implement a solver, like `fzn-gecode`, however it often wouldn't be useful enough. Another idea would be to create a program with your heuristic algorithm that supports the MiniZinc data input. This would allow you to use your heuristic and MiniZinc solvers on the same data. (JSON would be a good option for your data in this case)

Comment: Thanks again for the clarifications. Just a last question - say for e.g. I write up my heuristic in JSON. How can I then with the JSON file, .mzn model file, and .dzn data file, implement the heuristic to the model?

Comment: You would write an algorithm that takes an json file and produce the same output as a MiniZinc solver would. Then if you create a MiniZinc model of the same problem, you can use them interchangeably, as they will have the same output.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I'll try it out :)